# Convert DateTimeOffset to Int64 and back to DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#

I need to add DateTimeOffset to a binary serialization library that I maintain.  With DateTime I am simply saving the ticks as an Int64 but the DateTimeOffset does not have ticks as a constructor.  How can it be re-constructed properly?

**Example**

```
DateTime date = new DateTime.Now;
long ticks = date.Ticks;
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(ticks);

DateTimeOffset dateOffset = new DateTimeOffset.Now;
long ticks2 = dateOffset.Ticks;
DateTimeOffset dateOffset2 = new DateTimeOffset(?)
```

Comment: First hit on [Google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=datetimeoffset+from+ticks): [Reconstructing the DateTimeOffset from UTC Ticks](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/b5113ad0-0e21-43cc-aee9-412f12f54c03/reconstructing-the-datetimeoffset-from-utc-ticks?forum=csharpgeneral) Also; second hit: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/instantiating-a-datetimeoffset-object): `dateAndTime = new DateTimeOffset(633452259920000000, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));`. I suggest you use UtcTicks.

Comment: What do you think about using DateTimeOffset.FromFileTime and DateTimeOffset.ToFileTime ?  The docs say it is a UTC value. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tofiletime?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: If that fits your needs then why not?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` returns a `DateTime` value with `Kind` set to `DateTimeKind.Local` whereas the `DateTime(Int64)` constructor creates a value with `Kind` set to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  This statement will fail: `Debug.Assert(date.Kind.Equals (date2.Kind), "DateTime Kind mismatch");`  To serialize a `DateTime` in a way that considers `Kind` use the `DateTime.ToBinary()` and `DateTime.FromBinary(Int64)` methods.  Even then, the value returned by `FromBinary` may not match the original - see the warnings [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tobinary#remarks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> DateTimeOffset does not have ticks as a constructor

It does have a constructor that [takes ticks plus an offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTimeOffset__ctor_System_DateTime_System_TimeSpan_) …

```
DateTimeOffset(Int64, TimeSpan)
```

… and TimeSpan can be constructed [from a ticks value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_TimeSpan__ctor_System_Int64_) …

```
TimeSpan(Int64)
```

… so, you can serialize a `DateTimeOffset` to **two** `Int64` values …

```
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.Now;

var ticks = dto.Ticks;
var offset = dto.Offset.Ticks;

DateTimeOffset newDto = new DateTimeOffset(ticks, new TimeSpan(offset));

Debug.Assert(dto.EqualsExact(newDto), "DateTmeOffset Mismatch");
```

Comment: Just use UTC values then you can ignore the timespan altogether and use a single `Int64` value (and use `TimeSpan.Zero`). Exactly [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350188/convert-datetimeoffset-to-int64-and-back-to-datetimeoffset?noredirect=1#comment91645650_52350188).

Comment: @RobIII Changing a `DateTimeOffset` into a `DateTime` would indeed mean that you could use a single `Int64`.  But then the serialized item wouldn't be a `DateTimeOffset`!

Comment: Who said anything about a `DateTime`? I was referring to a `DateTimeOffset`

Comment: I would argue that if you have a `DateTimeOffset`, convert to UTC and discard the 'Offset' you essentially have a `DateTime` with `Kind` set to `Utc`.  For many uses, UTC (and `DateTime`) are entirely appropriate.  **But** if `DateTimeOffset` is being used one would assume the offset is significant.  Consider a `DateTimeOffset` for 11:00 am today in California (9/17/2018 11:00:00 AM -07:00) and another for 2:00 pm today in New York (9/17/2018 2:00:00 PM -04:00).  Both are 9/17/2018 6:00:00 PM +00:00.  In many cases UTC is sufficient but not if you need to know the offset as well as the time.

Comment: But all that wasn't the question. OP asked to convert a `DateTimeOffset` to `int64` and back (see title: _"Convert DateTimeOffset to Int64 and back to DateTimeOffset"_). If the offset is important, then, yes, ofcourse you need to (de)serialize that too but then a single `int64` won't be enough.